# what is the purpose of "this.lblDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lblDelete_Click); " in InitializeComponent() method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delegates

I am a newbie to asp.net, can you please explain the line of code below?

```
this.lblDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lblDelete_Click);
```

I don't know much about events and delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the code attaches an event handler to an event so that it can be, well... handled.

A simple way to understand it would be.

This event:

```
this.lblDelete.Click
```

Has this event handler attached:

```
+= new System.EventHandler
```

Which calls this method:

```
lblDelete_Click
```

Comment: But there is no method named 'lblDelete_Click'

Comment: Does the class that the codes in inherit from something else? If so the method maybe in the base class

Comment: The class is inheriting from another class, but that class(base) doesn't have any lblDelete_Click method. FYI.. this is available in child class only and it will be fired onclick of Delete LinkButton control.